# How to output data in angularjs template from multiple data source service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

Lets say these is my codes:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])  factory("dataProvider", function($resource) {
return {
  users: $resource('http://127.0.0.1/dbapi/users/:userId/:data', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
  }),
  comments: $resource('http://127.0.0.1/dbapi/comments/:userId/:data', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
  })
};  });
```

I want to display some info about the user and ng-repeat the comments in the same html template. How would I have to do that? 
the data is coming from rest api remote server in ionic app. please explain how to code the controller and the html code i am very new to angularjs and javascript.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign api responses to the model and access it in the view. 
Lets say we stored in the model **items** model. 
In the controller or service invoked the api call place

```
$scope.items = data;
```

lets say you have data as

```
var data = [
{"id": "1"},  
{"id": "2"}, 
{"id": "3"},
{"id": "4"},
{"id": "5"},
{"id": "6"}
```

];

and the html loop through the items

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

sample JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/1144/